# Get sessions info in #google-apis-explorer

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-apis-explorer

I use unique IDs for clients. Once user enters the site, I use google tag manager to save client ID in analytics dimension3.
Once an e-commerce event is triggered, I use google analytics API to request info for that particular user sessions using filter dimension3==XXX (client ID)

**For every session of the selected user I want to get from Google Analytics:**

1. When the session started
2. Landing page
3. Session duration
4. Operating system, browser, screen resolution, referrer, medium and some other general parameters.

What I'm looking for is a way to get information like in `Google Analytics -> Audience -> User report` (where you can see what a particular user was doing).

But as far as I can judge Google Analytics API can provide only summarized info (metrics divided by dimensions). It's more like SELECT GROUP BY statement but I meed more like SELECT WHERE.

Is there a way to get what I need?

PS. I request the following dimensions:
ga:fullReferrer, ga:landingPagePath, ga:operatingSystem, ga:mobileDeviceMarketingName, ga:source, ga:dateHourMinute, ga:dimension3, ga:screenResolution, ga:browser, ga:browserVersion, ga:medium, ga:dateHourMinute, ga:sessionDurationBucket (2 requests in a batch)
The metric I use is: ga:sessions

What I get is not really what I need for I need information on SESSION (eg there were 30 sessions, I need 30 rows in the result, instead I may get 1000 rows result because analytics splits the metrics into dimensions... ))))

Comment: Have you tried using a filter?  [HERE](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/reference#filters)